# Wandb Sweep tuning define output directory

Tags: logging, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, wandb

Please can be defined output directory for wandb when running sweep tuning?

I've defined directory using `wandb.init(dir="./out/")`, but `./out/` is used only for output of runs, but `./wandb/` folder is created in the directory from which I am running scripts. Can be wandb sweet output directory defined too, so that it uses the same directory as for runs (in my case `./out/`) ?

Current final structure after runing script looks like:

```
./out/wandb/
./wandb
```

And I want only:

```
./out/wandb
```

Comment: Can you share a colab notebook or script (as gist) to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can setup the environment variable `WANDB_DIR` by doing

```bash
export WANDB_DIR=~full_path/out/
```

I am running the sweep from the terminal by doing:

```bash
> wandb sweep sweep_file.yaml
> wandb agent sweep_id --count 1
```

[image]

As you can see, the runs go to the `out/` folder